# XML Schema data type for file path

Tags: xml, xsd

I am relatively new to work related to XML Schema and have been trying to figure out which XML Schema datatype I should use for a file path. Is it string or anyURI which is most accurate in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend [`xsd:anyURI`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#anyURI)

> [Definition:]   **anyURI** represents a Uniform Resource Identifier
>   Reference (URI). An **anyURI** value can be absolute or relative, and may
>   have an optional fragment identifier (i.e., it may be a URI
>   Reference). This type should be used to specify the intention that the
>   value fulfills the role of a URI as defined by [[RFC 2396]](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#RFC2396), as amended
>   by [[RFC 2732]](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#RFC2732).

with no scheme component for relative paths or a `file` scheme component for absolute paths.

**Examples**:

- `../path/to/filename.txt`
- `file:///c:/path/to/filename.txt`